# How to solve $1/x + x + \log(x)/2 = y$ for $x$

Tags: special-functions, lambert-w

It seems related to the [Lambert-W function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lambert_W_function) $W$, because

$$x = W(xe^x) = W(\exp(\log(x)+x))$$

But I can't quite figure out how to use it here, and neither can Wolfram, REDUCE (Computer Algebra System), or Sympy

Comment: I'm not sure but I think that there is no nice form even with Lambert-W function

Answer (score 4):

I do not think that you could find an analytical solution to the problem and, for a given $y$, you will need a numerical method.

Consider $$f(x)=x+\frac{1}{x}+\frac{1}{2}\log (x)$$
$$f'(x)=1-\frac{1}{x^2}+\frac{1}{2 x}$$ The first derivative cancels at $$x_*=\frac{1}{4} \left(\sqrt{17}-1\right)\implies f(x_*)=\frac{1}{2} \left(\sqrt{17}+\log \left(\frac{1}{4}
   \left(\sqrt{17}-1\right)\right)\right)\approx 1.93782$$ and this is a minimum.

So, the equation $f(x)=a$ has two solutions provided $a >f(x_*)$, one double solution if $a =f(x_*)$ and no solution if $a <f(x_*)$.

In the case where two roots exist, they will be such that $0 < x_1 < x_*$ and $a < x_2 < \infty$.

Newton method will work just as a charm for the largest root since the function is almost linear.

For the smallest root, to make life easier, I would suggest to set $x=\frac 1y$ and to solve for $y$
$$g(y)=y+\frac{1}{y}-\frac{1}{2}\log (y)=a$$

**Edit**

As said, Newton method will work very fine and will require very few iterations to converge.

To show it, let us make **one** single iteration starting using $x_0=y_0=a$. The first iterates are given by
$$x_1=\frac{a \left(2 a^2+a-a \log (a)-4\right)}{2 a^2+a-2} \qquad \qquad y_1=\frac{a \left(2 a^2-a+a \log (a)-4\right)}{2 a^2-a-2}$$

The table below shows, for a few values of $a$, the first iterate and the exact solution.
$$\left(
\begin{array}{ccccc}
 a & x_1 & x_{sol} & y_1 & y_{sol} \\
 3 & 2.16382 &  2.15212 & 3.29904 &  3.29197 \\
 4 & 3.11233 &  3.11108 & 4.54541 &  4.53548 \\
 5 & 4.05215 &  4.05351 & 5.70316 &  5.69409 \\
 6 & 4.99338 &  4.99555 & 6.82036 &  6.81260 \\
 7 & 5.93835 &  5.94075 & 7.91404 &  7.90744 \\
 8 & 6.88743 &  6.88984 & 8.99224 &  8.98659 \\
 9 & 7.84038 &  7.8427 & 10.0594 &  10.0546 \\
 10 & 8.79683 &  8.79903 & 11.1184 &  11.1141 \\
 11 & 9.75639 &  9.75846 & 12.1709 &  12.1672 \\
 12 & 10.7187 &  10.7206 & 13.2183 &  13.2150
\end{array}
\right)$$

We could even do better  making **one** single iteration of Halley method starting using again $x_0=y_0=a$. The first iterates are given by
$$x_1=\frac{8 a^4+8 a^3-22 a^2-(4 a+1) a^2 \log (a)-10 a+8}{8 a^3+8 a^2-14 a+(a-4) \log
   (a)-6}$$
$$y_1=\frac{8 a^4-8 a^3-22 a^2+(4 a-1) a^2 \log (a)+10 a+8}{8 a^3-8 a^2-14 a+(a+4) \log
   (a)+6}$$ and get the following results
$$\left(
\begin{array}{ccccc}
 a & x_1 & x_{sol} & y_1 & y_{sol} \\
 3 & 2.15764 &  2.15212 & 3.29122 &  3.29197 \\
 4 & 3.11233 &  3.11108 & 4.53421 &  4.53548 \\
 5 & 4.05384 &  4.05351 & 5.69296 &  5.69409 \\
 6 & 4.99559 &  4.99555 & 6.81169 &  6.81260 \\
 7 & 5.94069 &  5.94075 & 7.90672 &  7.90744 \\
 8 & 6.88974 &  6.88984 & 8.98602 &  8.98659 \\
 9 & 7.84259 &  7.84270 & 10.0541 &  10.0546 \\
 10 & 8.79892 &  8.79903 & 11.1138 & 11.1141\\
 11 & 9.75835 & 9.75846 &  12.1669 &  12.1672 \\
 12 & 10.7205 &  10.7206 & 13.2147 &  13.2150
\end{array}
\right)$$

For sure, the successive derivatives being very simple, we could continue this process using [higher order iterations](http://numbers.computation.free.fr/Constants/Algorithms/newton.html). For example, for the case where $a=3$, **one** single iteration of Houselholder method would lead to $x_1=2.15277$ and $y_1=3.29197$. Going further, the almost exact solutions would be obtained analytically.

Comment: +1 That's awesome, thank you so much! I'm not going to accept your answer because it isn't a closed form in terms of some common function, and you don't have a proof that you can't.

However otherwise this was an extremely good answer and was sufficient for my needs :)

Comment: @Phylliida. There is no closed form.

Comment: why doesn’t it have one?

Comment: @Phylliida. In fact, there is one closed form solution in terms of *Phylliida function* which just appeared. Joke, for sure. Cheers :-)